# Are ASP.NET MVC HTML Helpers overrated?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, coding-style, html-helper

It is quite possible that I may not have got the point, but I really can't figure out how ASP.NET MVC's HTML Helpers can help me. Here's a sample: -

HTML:

```
<a href="ActionName" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

HTML Helper:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click me", "ActionName", null, new {target="blank"}) %>
```

My eyes are reading HTML more easily, and it seems counter-intuitive to use the HTML Helpers.

Look at the following arguments:

- A lot of people (even novices) know how to read HTML. The HTML Helper syntax can confuse easily.
- In many cases you need to do more typing writing an HTML 'helper', then you need to write the actual HTML.
- The HTML Helper is going to spew real HTML anyway, so why not write HTML directly?
- Writing HTML gives you more control over the syntax, and the standards. You can make it conform to whatever HTML standard you want.

Are there any special compelling reasons that I have not understood (since I am self-educated in MVC and there could be gaps) that should make me want to prefer HTML Helpers?

Or are they just code noise?

Comment: But see, if you use the <a> method, then you get seen as archaic by elitist developers who think they're just hot s*** on a stick because they know the flavor of the week.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The primary reason you don't use `<a>` tags directly is that you don't want to hardcode URLs in your application. The `Html.ActionLink` method will abstract away the URL generation and you'll specify the controller, action, and other parameters.

So, basically, the two lines you posted in your question are not really equivalent. You should consider adding the dynamic URL generation code to the `<a>` tag to make them functionally equivalent. Beside that, if you output HTML directly, you'll have to be extremely careful about HTML encoding stuff. `Html.ActionLink` will do this job for you too.

Comment: Youu can still use <a> tags and keep the URL dynamic (non-hardcoded) by doing <%= Model.LinkUrl %> or <%= MyUrlProvider.Someurl %> inside the href attribute.

Comment: I've been hard-coding URLs this way <a href='./home/login/'>login</a>. What could go wrong? Also what are the other HTML helpers for apart from action-link?

Comment: @Cyril:  What if you reorganize your site so there is another level, like "/company/home/login"?  You'd have to go through manually and change your links, instead of in one centralized location.

Comment: @Cyril: What if the URL contained some parameters? For example, SO generates dynamic URL for each question. You are not able to hardcode it. @Alex: Don't forget the need to sanitize inputs or you'll be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: For parameters i use generated URLs, the approach prescribed by Alex.

Comment: @Cyril: As I said, adding textual parameters adds the need for HTML encoding. Additionally, a single view file might be referenced by different actions from different URLs so relative URLs may not work.

Comment: +1 Mehrdad for being so informative (though I did that yesterday itself)

Comment: URLs that are generated with ActionLink also respect the routes you have set up in Global.asax.

Comment: +1 So, how would it generate the URL if I host my site under a subdirectory? `products/list/all` OR `/subDirectory/products/list/all`? And does `Url.Action` generate URL in same way?

Comment: @Ismail: That shouldn't be different from the simple case. Whatever you have in your route table will be printed out. That said, you may be interested in looking into areas as well.

Comment: None of this explains why `<a href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'>Link</a>` is in any way less preferable to using `ActionLink`.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say that you have many query parameters in the URL like

site.com?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=1&f=1

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click me", "ActionName", null, new {a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=1, f=1}) %>
```

The actionlink can build this URL for you. If you didn't have the helper you would have to manually add keys and vlaues to the URL. And this is a real pain. The URL helper can also match URL routes too.

Comment: +1 for this very good instance of a "for" rather than an "against."

Answer (score 7):

Even better, use MvcContrib and ditch the error prone "magic strings" and replace them with lambdas.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<MyController>(x => x.ActionName() ,"Click me",new {target="blank"}) %>
```

Comment: Yes I saw the interesting 'fluent html'. But seriously, that's absolutely for geeks! Though I am a self-confessed one, they make me very afraid. They don't look so readable.

Comment: Using the lambda expressions might cause problems because of the [ActionName("..")] attribute. IMHO it's better to avoid them.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with why you should use HTML helpers rather than raw HTML, unless your argument is that a 3rd party library has extended ActionLink to allow you to use strongly-typed references to generate the link, except it seems that the same code behind that link could extend the `UrlHelper` so you can create the anchor tag yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's no big difference between

```
<a href="ActionName" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

and

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click me", "ActionName", null, new {target="blank"}) %>
```

because in both cases you're hardcoding (URL in the first, action name in the latter).

That's why I create specific helper methods for links, and then I use

```
<%= Html.LinkSomeAction("Click me") %>
```

This way I'm sure that when I'll change my mind on which name the action should have, I'll be fine; also, I'll never have to worry about misstyping action names or links.

The solution proposed by mxmissile is also good.

Comment: This could lead to a lot of un-necessary method overloading, what if you wanted to add css classes or control the data that gets generated in the route. Your action names should not be changing that much, IMO. Action names should be meaningful and routes should be helpful for users.